# Why does my build.gradle.kts not read in values from build.properties correctly?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I have a `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file that looks like

```
artifactory_contextUrl=https://my.artifactory.com
artifactory_user=user
artifactory_password=pass
```

I have in my project a `build.gradle.kts` that looks like

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31"
}

dependencies {
 ...
}
repositories {
    val artifactory_contextUrl: String by project
    val artifactory_user: String by project
    val artifactory_password: String by project
    maven {
        url = uri("${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-gradle-org-cache")
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
* Where:
Build file 'myProject/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts' line: 15

* What went wrong:
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @b1a58a3; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

If I try to add a debug println right after `val artifactory_contextUrl: String by project` I get

```
  Line 15:     println("Artifactory contextUrl (In repositories block): ${artifactory_contextUrl}")
                                                                             ^ Unresolved reference: artifactory_contextUrl
```

Why doesn't this work? I even tried passing the properties as `-Partifactory_user` etc on the command line to no effect.

And I also tried adding a `~/.gradle/init.gradle` with

```
allprojects {

    ext {
        artifactory_user  = "${artifactory_user}"
        artifactory_password  = "${artifactory_password}"
        artifactory_contextUrl= "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    }
}
```

Which also fails even though I have the env vars for artifactory_user etc set. Is there something wrong with how I'm doing `String by project`?

Answer (score 0):

The error you showed is because of your `init.gradle` file.
It sets the extra properties to GStrings (Groovy String with variable substitution).
Then by using the `val artifactory_contextUrl: String by project` you try to assign that `GString` instance to a `String` variable, with naturally fails outside of Groovy code.

Remove the init script. Just having the values in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` as you showed is enough. You said that also didn't work, but would be content for another question as you for sure would get a different error message as you can only get this error message when using Groovy somewhere.

If you would keep that strange init script, either make the lines like `artifactory_user = artifactory_user`, because it makes no sense to use a `GString` to insert one `String` when you already have it as `String`, or make it `artifactory_user  = "${artifactory_user}" as String` to make Groovy right away evaluate the `GString` to the end result and make it a plain old `String`.